# Mongoosejs populate and aggregate subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a '3-layered' relationship in MongooseJS like so, it's two one-to-many relationships between subdocuments. Like so:

```
var BroadcastSchema = new Schema({
...
    _donationAddresses: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'DonationAddress'
    }]
});


var DonationAddressSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    _donations: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Donation'
    }]
});

var DonationSchema = new Schema({
...
    amount: Number
});
```

I want to get the `$sum` total of the `amount:Number` on the `DonationSchema`

So far I've populated the `Donation` by using a work-around listed [here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1381) (because as far as I know you can't *populate a populate* so [far as I know](https://thecodebarbarian.wordpress.com/2013/06/06/61/))

```
Broadcast.find()
    .exec(function(err, broadcasts) {
         // this works
        var iter = function(broadcast, callback) {
            DonationAddress.populate(broadcast._donationAddresses, {
                path: '_donations'
            }, callback);
        };

         // tried to iterate over the donation address and 
         // aggregate the _donations.amount
        var iter2 = function(broadcast, callback) {
            DonationAddress.aggregate([{
                $match: {
                    _id: broadcast._donationAddresses
                }
            }, {
                $unwind: "$_donations"
            }, {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$_id",
                    total: {
                        $sum: "$_donations.amount"
                    }
                }
            }], callback);
        };

        async.each(broadcasts, iter, function done(err) {
            async.each(broadcasts, iter2, function done(err) {
                 res.json(broadcasts);
            });
        });
```

Comment: Population is a mongoose "client side" operation. There is no server side joining of data here, it actually performs additional queries in order to pull the documents. Aggregation is sever side and requires the elements to be **embedded** within a single collection. So where your references are to external documents, this cannot work.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I'll just add to the total when adding the `Donations` to the `DonationAddress`

Comment: In general usage patterns, if you can "add things up as you go" then do it. It saves calculating at run-time with each request. If that is too hefty then manually sum up things as a background process and run periodically. Or of course just embed your data if you can.